# Invalid column using dplyr + NSE

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

The following code works fine on my mac, using CRAN R:

```
delta_scores <- function(df, data_var) {
  # Use Hadley's new non-standard evaluation helpers to compute differences in 
  # the symbol passed through data_var from Session 1 to 2. Assumes an ID column
  # in df that groups units of measurement.

  # For the RHS:
  quo_data_var <- enquo(data_var)
  # For the LHS, we need yet another step (basically a string)
  name_data_var <- quo_name(quo_data_var)

  df %>% select(ID, Session, !!quo_data_var) %>% 
    # NSE spread stopped working on my windows machine!
    spread(Session, !!quo_data_var) %>% 
    # Note use of := instead of plain = to support NSE
    transmute(ID=ID, !!name_data_var := `2`-`1`)
}

test_df <- data_frame(ID=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
                      Session=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
                      Measure=c(1,2,3,1,1,4))

delta_scores(test_df, Measure)
```

But when I run it on Windows, Microsoft R Open 3.4.2, dplyr 0.7.3, I get:

```
Error: Invalid column specification
```

NOTE: it's easy enough to fix by replacing `spread` with `spread_('Session', name_data_var)`. Interestingly, the `select` call works fine (my real data frames have many columns). I'm concerned about the bigger issue of dplyr's NSE not working in a given environment.

Looking at the debugger stacktrace was daunting enough that I decided to ask for help here first. Any ideas about what's going on or ideas on how to debug this are much appreciated!

Comment: On `0.7.4` it is working fine

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with tidyr (which makes sense - that's where spread is defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved in later versions of tidyr. Confirmed working in tidyr 0.7.2. Support for Hadley's new NSE (non-standard evaluation) system was added in the 0.7 release.